# What is the use of adding Google Ads (using AdMob) in our application..?

Tags: android, admob

As I am new to the android technology I want to get some information from you people regarding google ads in our application.

As I have integrated google ads in our project recently, I just want to know what is the use of adding google ads in our application. Will the publisher will get any benefits (like earning money or free advertisement). Can anyone give me some clear cut clarification regarding the main benefits of adding google ads in our app.

Comment: obviously publisher of ads would get handy returns while running ads in app

Comment: That means if I have added google ads in my own application means will there be any chance of earning free money (on publishing ads in my own apps)...

Comment: that's what i'm saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the publisher (that's the name for those providing ad space in their apps) you will be able to earn revenue for displaying ads from the ad networks. You can also display house ads if you have other apps/sites that you want to promote.

I would suggest using a mediation platform so that you can pick and choose which ad networks to use. Admob (Google Ads) provides such a service.

Comment: So, in that case if i have included google ads in my application through Admob how the earnings will be credited to my account. Should i have to provide any bank related details to google for crediting money in my account (earned from google ads)...?

Comment: Yes. If you go into your Admob Account, go to the Payment section and fill in the details.